# How does Delphi 7 find all the dcu files during compilation?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I am helping a coworker set up his computer so that his Delphi 7 environment works like mine. He has Delphi 7 installed plus the third party tools we use. We have a Delphi app with source. It compiles fine on my computer but when he compiles it on his computer, it keeps coming up with 'file not found' errors for many dcu files.  These are dcu files of third party components, either which come with Delphi IDE or have been installed manually.

I renamed his C:\Program Files (x86)\Borland folder and copied my whole Borland folder structure to his so that he has what I have.  So now his Delphi IDE and the app structure resembles mine, yet he still gets missing dcu's. Every time he gets a missing dcu, he adds its path to Delphi's 'Search path' list. For some dcu's, they exist in different folders which means we have to troubleshoot further to make sure we picked the correct version. My 'Search Path' is empty as shown below which tells me my Delphi doesn't use this entry to search for dcu's. Our computer's PATH environment variable entry has the same values for anything related to Delphi.

My question is why my delphi app compiles fine as it finds all the dcu's it needs which reside in different folders yet his Delphi is not finding them when we have the same folder structure and PATH?

How does the Delphi IDE finds all the dcu's it needs during compilation? What is left now to look at is the registry. Are the search patterns in the registry? Where? (We also have Delphi XE installed if this means anything)

[image]

Comment: What happened to the useful comments from @RobKennedy?

Comment: @David Rob was under the assumption OP just copied the program files from one PC to the other, and I pointed out that it appears OP did proper install (and just overwrote the files). I can't imagine how Delphi would work at all without the registry entries anyway.

Answer (score 5):

You don't want to add these directories to your project's search path. That will make it so that only this project is able to use these components. Instead, you need to do this in the global library path, which applies for all projects. Check the library path of your existing installation, surely you'll find a large list of directories here.

`Main Menu -> Tools -> Environment options dialog -> Library page -> Library Path edit box`

Comment: I am not very familiar with Delphi. Check how..where? A setting? The folder structure? ..?

Comment: Have a look at http://www.delphisources.ru/pages/faq/master-delphi-7/content/LiB0009.html#26 for a discussion of and an image of the Delphi 7 Environment Options dialog

Answer (score 1):

They are the output paths, try looking in the following location 
Tools > Options > Environment Options > delphi Options > Paths and Directories
 This tells the IDE what source files to include. The only other difference can be if you system variables are different if you have any.

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/Library

Comment: Your link is for Delphi XE8, which is extremely different from Delphi 7. Sure, the concept is the same, but where to find these options is entirely different.

Comment: Pathing is same in d7 im using d7

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what this adds to @JerryDodge's answer?

Comment: @MartynA It was posted very shortly after mine.

Comment: @JerryDodge:  Sure, one of the limitations of SO, I guess (not being able to see newly-arriving answers while writing your own I mean).  But I'm not sure I agree with the comment "The only other difference..", as the PATH affects what BPLs the IDE finds/loads, but not, so far as I recall (possibly incorrectly) what DCUs.